# Xcode API call with XAuth

Tags: xcode, api

I am trying to make an api call with the xboxapi.com api they provide:

```
curl -s -H "X-AUTH: 5fd3aa766f7e3f4e190b797384d5fdb27bf81" https://xboxapi.com/v2/accountXuid
```

(I took out a few characters from above x-auth key)

My code so far:

```
NSURLRequest* urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://xboxapi.com/v2/2533274866541819/friends"]];

NSURLResponse* response = nil;
NSError* error = nil;
NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSString* myData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSLog(myData);
```

As you can see its just making a raw call to the api with no X-Auth. So Im getting a response that says no API key provided. How do I add this? Would appreciate any help.